# Use pre-existing socket with thrift server?

Tags: c++, thrift

If I have a pre-existing open file descriptor, referring to an already bound and listening socket, how can I use it to initialize a thrift server object (the non-blocking server preferably) and start accepting RPC requests? The various ThriftSocket objects I've seen only accept address/port (or just port) arguments to create a socket themselves.

Answer (score 0):

For the client side, you have a constructor to construct a socket from a file descriptor:

```
/**
   * Constructor to create socket from file descriptor.
   */
  TSocket(THRIFT_SOCKET socket, std::shared_ptr<TConfiguration> config = nullptr);
```

On Unix system, you can find out that `THRIFT_SOCKET` is an `int`, just feed your descriptor here!

Unfortunately, this is not the case for the server side. Inheriting `TServerSocket` won't solve your issue because the internal socket member is private.

However, the thrift servers all take a `TServerTransport` as argument. Thus, the idea is to inherit `TServerTransport` to create a custom `TServerSocket`. The original `TServerSocket` can be of help here.

But, the fact they did not add the possibility for this feature might mean it is not safe to do so. You'll have no other choice that inspecting `TServerSocket.cpp` to check the internal implementation.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. TServerSocket and TNonblockingServerSocket, which the server examples I've seen use, don't have a constructor like this. Can a TSocket be safely substituted for a TServerSocket? They don't appear to share parent classes.

Comment: @randian You're wright, this is only for the client API, my mistake. I'll update the answer.